# How to handle kafka exceptions?

Tags: java, error-handling, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I tried to intentionally stop kafka to know what exceptions it is throwing, so far I got the following:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
java.io.EOFException: null
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
```

Any idea how to catch these exceptions in Java?
Once I catch these, I want to restart kafka and/or zookeeper similar to these commands in the terminal:

```
kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties
zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
```

Or is there any other way to correctly handle connection errors?
I'm using Kafka 0.10 with high level consumers.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are trying to do here. You want to run Kafka and Zookeeper and ensure both services are restarted when they fail? In that case I wouldn't recommend any java solution but instead look at running them as a service with SysV, SystemD or Upstart and configure them to restart on failure.. But I may be misreading your question.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to restart them when it failed. But is there any way to let the app know that there was a failure (besides generated logs)? Since I can't seem to catch it in my app. Thanks!

Comment: You wouldn't be able to catch it in your app, as the server runs in a different jvm, so you don't get to see the exceptions that it throws. What you'd need to do is check the futures of your produce requests, those will contain exceptions, if the send failed. For the consumer, last I checked the .poll() request will block indefinitely (well, there is a limit, but effectively indefinitely) until the broker returns. You'd need to have some sort of check when the last successful poll returned to be aware of this. Happy to write a proper answer if this is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks Sonke! I tried to catch the error in the producer by adding a get(1000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) from the future. But I only get WARN from consumer when I try to intentionally stop kafka, even when I assigned a value of 1000 to request.timeout.ms and session.timeout.ms. And it keeps logging every second. Giving me java.net.ConnectException and java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null. Also, I don't use KafkaConsumer so I don't have poll, instead I use KafkaStreams.

Comment: Try to add a call to .flush() after having sent your messages. That will block until all of them have completed, either successfully or unsuccessfully. After that has returned call .get() on all futures, if that doesn't throw an exception your messages have been sent.

Comment: This is for the producer, correct? What about detecting the error in consumer? Also, both the producer and consumer will run 24 hrs. So the producer will continuously send messages. Not sure if I can wait for all to be completed.